# Change part of table column size

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, columns, dimensions

I would like to know if there is a way, that I can resize part of a column, while keeping the rest the same size. Such that I would get this:

Column
_________|
_________|
_________|
_________________|
_________________|
_________________|

I have included my project below as tex and an image. The cells in want to change is Column 1, row 1 to Column 1, row 9.

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{center}
\caption*{\Huge {\bf Tjanseplan}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Tidspunkt         & Type                    & Lørdag                                         & Søndag            & Mandag             & Tirsdag            \\ \hline
    13:37             & Antikaos                 &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}                        & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne    & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene        & \cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne       \\ \hline
    13:37             & Morgenmad            &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}                                & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne        & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene           & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne       \\ \hline
    13:37             & Oprydning              &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}                      & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne      & \cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne       & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne     \\ \hline
    13:37             & Frokost                  & \cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne    & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene       & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne     &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}    \\ \hline
    13:37             & Oprydning              & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne       & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene          & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene        &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}    \\ \hline
    13:37             & Aftensmad             & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne                                   & \cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne      & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene           &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}   \\ \hline
    13:37             & Oprydning             & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene                                    & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne    & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne       &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}    \\ \hline
    13:37             & Bolledej            & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene  & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne   & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne      &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8} \\  \hline  
\multicolumn{1}{ l }{} \\ \hline
\cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne          & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne            & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne       & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene       & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene           & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne     \\ \hline
    Camilla Kiel         & Nadia Willumsen         & Alberte Thegler    & Hjalte Abelskov   & Kasper Hedegaard   & Simon Munck        \\ \hline
    Adam Honeré       & Nick Pedersen           & Adrian Westh       & Morten Dreier     & Troels Thomsen     & Emilie Damkjær     \\ \hline
    Martin Poulsen    & Morten Thaysen          & Sune Bartels   & Thomas Lorentzen       & Oliver Celest      & Troels Leskes      \\ \hline
    Mikkel Kristensen & Simon Schleicher        & Jesper Christensen & Jeppe Hansen      & Stefan Duro        & Lasse Jensen       \\ \hline
    Mikkel Knudsen    & Louise Hrouda-Rasmussen & Oliver Nielsen     & Mike Andersson    & Anna Vita Ross     & Signe Jensen       \\ \hline
    Rasmus Andersen   & Sebastian Jensen        & Peter Meyer        & Peter Salomonsson & Sebastian Scheerer & Nikolaj Østergaard \\ \hline
    ~                 & ~         & ~   & ~                 & ~                & Rasmus Haarslev   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

[image: Image of project]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean something like:

[image]

In which case it's easiest to insert extra columns and the use `\multicolumn` to merge columns in the two halves. I disabled the colours as you didn't supply any code defining them and I don't think they are related to the question.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\textwidth2\textwidth
\pdfpagewidth1.2\textwidth
\usepackage{colortbl}

\renewcommand\cellcolor[2][]{}

\begin{document}
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
\hspace*{-2in}\begin{tabular}{|l|ll|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    Tidspunkt         & 
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{Type}                    & Lørdag                                         & Søndag            & Mandag             & Tirsdag            \\ \hline
    13:37             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Antikaos}                 &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}                        & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne    & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene        & \cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne       \\ \hline
    13:37             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Morgenmad}            &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}                                & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne        & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene           & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne       \\ \hline
    13:37             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Oprydning}              &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}                      & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne      & \cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne       & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne     \\ \hline
    13:37             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Frokost}                  & \cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne    & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene       & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne     &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}    \\ \hline
    13:37             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Oprydning}              & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne       & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene          & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene        &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}    \\ \hline
    13:37             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Aftensmad}             & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne                                   & \cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne      & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene           &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}   \\ \hline
    13:37             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Oprydning}             & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene                                    & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne    & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne       &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8}    \\ \hline
    13:37             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Bolledej}            & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene  & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne   & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne      &  \cellcolor[gray]{0.8} \\  \hline  
\multicolumn{1}{ l }{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{Smørkærnerne_color}Smørkærnerne}         & \cellcolor{Kvægdriverne_color}Kvægdriverne            & \cellcolor{Laderejserne_color}Laderejserne       & \cellcolor{Fuksvansene_color}Fuksvansene       & \cellcolor{Høtyvene_color}Høtyvene           & \cellcolor{Gyldesprederne_color}Gyldesprederne     \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Camilla Kiel}         & Nadia Willumsen         & Alberte Thegler    & Hjalte Abelskov   & Kasper Hedegaard   & Simon Munck        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Adam Honeré}       & Nick Pedersen           & Adrian Westh       & Morten Dreier     & Troels Thomsen     & Emilie Damkjær     \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Martin Poulsen}    & Morten Thaysen          & Sune Bartels   & Thomas Lorentzen       & Oliver Celest      & Troels Leskes      \\ \hline
   \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Mikkel Kristensen} & Simon Schleicher        & Jesper Christensen & Jeppe Hansen      & Stefan Duro        & Lasse Jensen       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Mikkel Knudsen}   & Louise Hrouda-Rasmussen & Oliver Nielsen     & Mike Andersson    & Anna Vita Ross     & Signe Jensen       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Rasmus Andersen}   & Sebastian Jensen        & Peter Meyer        & Peter Salomonsson & Sebastian Scheerer & Nikolaj Østergaard \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{    ~ }                & ~         & ~   & ~                 & ~                & Rasmus Haarslev   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```